# How to click on element using other related element?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

```
<ul class="ui-treenode-children">
<li aria-selected="true" aria-checked="true" aria-expanded="true" id="frmScrForm:multiLevelTree:0_0" data-rowkey="0_0" class="ui-treenode ui-treenode-parent folder" role="treeitem">
    <span class="ui-treenode-content ui-tree-selectable" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-checked="false">
        <span class="ui-tree-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
        <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget tree_node_folder_expand">
            <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="ui-treenode-icon ui-icon tree_node_folder_collaps"></span>
        <span class="ui-treenode-label ui-corner-all">
            <span class="tree_node_folder_text" style="background-color: transparent;">Company</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <ul class="ui-treenode-children" style="">
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am using selenium (selenium IDE) to test a tree, I want to click on the check box according to the text (or value) next to it.

This is the HTML code for one node in the tree, how can I use selenium to click at check box next to the text (company)??

Comment: You could try finding the Xpath of Element you wish to select by using Firepath(plug-in for FireBug). And use the Xpath to allow Selenium IDE to find the element on the page.

Comment: I see no checkbox (typically an `input` element) in this HTML.

Comment: @Lt_Shade:
Yes, I could that and I did but the problem is that the location of the element in the tree is changing not the text, so I want to locate the related check box by using the name (text)

Comment: @Arran: the check box is the <div> section with class="ui-chk-box ..."

Answer (score 0):

Please try using following xpath

```
selenium.click("xpath=//span[@class='ui-treenode-content ui-tree-selectable']
   [contains(text(),"Company")]/parent::span/span/div/div/span");
```